# Sitecore WFFM Client Side Validation of Required Fields

Tags: validation, sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2

Does Sitecore Webforms For Marketers allow for client side validation of required fields out of the box?

The documentation only mentions client side validation in relation to validators and nothing about the required field functionality.

We're running Sitecore 7.2, WFFM 2.4

Comment: It should. Does it not work? What happens? Do you get an error? Did you add jQuery and jQuery validation? What have you already done?

Comment: The client side validation doesn't fire, only server side, i dont think you have to add jQuery in yourself do you as WFFM loads its own scripts into the form? It is currently loading jquery.js, jquery-ui.min.js, jquery-ui.il8n.js, json2.min.js, head.load.min.js, sc.webform.js

Comment: @RobEarlam Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using a MVC (cshtml) Layout?
There are many bugs in the current version (2.4 rev.141008) of WFFM for MVC Layouts.

One of the bugs is about scripts missing on the form front-end.

Until a update comes, the workaround is to add these bundles to the \Views\Form\Index.cshtml file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wffm/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/wffm/scripts")
@Styles.Render("~/content/wffm/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/content/wffm/themes")
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

A validator item contains the Enable Script Validation field. Its purpose is to indicate whether or not client-side validation is enabled. I believe this is what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

To get the basic regex functionality or an validation working on a field you need to set these fields in the Forms Editor.

[image]

Then set the Validation field in the Behavior Section of your field i.e.

> /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field
>   Types/Custom/Custom Single Line Text